# How to get status of job using Scheduler?

Tags: python, scheduler, status

I have a scheduled job running on [Scheduler](https://python-scheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library, and I would like to get its status `("Success", "Failed")` from python but I can't find documentation on how to get the status.

Let's take as an example the following code to use the scheduler :

```
import datetime as dt
import time

from scheduler import Scheduler

import scheduler.trigger as trigger

def foo():

    print("foo")

schedule = Scheduler()
schedule.minutely(dt.time(second=15), foo)
while True:  

    schedule.exec_jobs()

    time.sleep(1)
```

I can only print the scheduler but I need to print the status of execution, is it possible ?

```
>>> print(schedule)  
max_exec=inf, tzinfo=None, priority_function=linear_priority_function, #jobs=9

type     function         due at                 due in      attempts weight
-------- ---------------- ------------------- --------- ------------- ------
MINUTELY foo(..)          2022-03-30 00:37:15   0:00:14         0/inf      1
```

Please advise

Comment: If you think that this feature is missing, I would be happy if you open an issue on the [project page](https://gitlab.com/DigonIO/scheduler) on GitLab.

Comment: @jpotyka Sure I can do, thanks! Additionnaly, I would like to take this opportunity to ask about another feature in the library if possible please. Is it possible to have the last datetime for an executed job ? I can find in the documentation that you provide ```datetime``` which is meant to get the datetime object for the planed execution but I was wondering if there was one for the last past execution of the job ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The job itself has no status message like ("Success", "Failed") because the job does not know if the logic in the scheduled function was "successful".
The user must therefore program the logic himself whether the execution has proceeded as desired.
If you want to know if the job was executed at all, regardless of the result, you can look at the number of executions.
The job has the properties `attempts`, `max_attempts` and `has_attempts_remaining` for this purpose. [Here](https://digon.io/hyd/project/scheduler/t/master/_autosummary/scheduler.threading.job.Job.html) you can find the doc page.
Maybe this [example](https://python-scheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/examples/metrics.html) can help you too.

*Disclosure: I am one of the authors of the library.*